# Where in the Angular JS application life cycle does this code load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Based on the code below, can someone tell me where in the Angular JS life cycle this code will be loaded. I am running into a very arcane timing issue where sometimes angularjs controllers that need the code below are loaded prior to the code below. Sometimes I can attempt to reproduce more than 100 times and the issue never occurs. I would like to to force this code to load before any other controllers.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
angular
    .module('securityMaintenance')
    .directive('buttons', buttons);

function buttons() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'app/shared/buttons/buttons.html',
        controller: ButtonsController,
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    };

    return directive;
}

ButtonsController.$inject = ['$location', '$route', '$scope', '$rootScope'];

// ReSharper disable once InconsistentNaming
function ButtonsController($location, $route, $scope, $rootScope) {
   ...
   init();

   function init() {}    
}  
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved mainly by using a priority member of directive that I found after days of searching in a GitHub repository. Anyway, it is angular JS and it seemed to have worked. The priority member is synonymous with a setting a threads priority or setting the z-index of an html element. It controls the compilation order of the templates, I guess.

```
function buttons() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'AE',
        priority: 100,
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'app/shared/buttons/buttons.html',
        controller: ButtonsController,
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    };

    return directive;
}
```